# Non-standard Gauss sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, roots-of-unity, trigonometric-sums

I have the following problem. Let $p$ be some prime. What is the value of 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k+1}{p}\right) \omega_p^{kl},
\end{equation}
where $\left(\frac{k+1}{p}\right)$ is the Legendre symbol, and $\omega_p = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}.$ [solved].

But what is the value of
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k^2+k}{p}\right) \omega_p^{kl}?
\end{equation}

I found the standard result for $\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)$, $\sqrt{p}$ or $i\sqrt{p},$ but I don't know the proof techniques and therefore don't know how to approach this one. Any ideas? I am not specialist in number theory, and I don't even know if it is easy or hard question :)

Any hints or links to references are welcomed.

What I actually need is the value (or a lower bound of the absolute value) of a Gauss sum with $\chi(k) = (\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)+1)(\left(\frac{k+1}{p}\right)+1).$

Comment: The missing term at $k = 0$ is $1$, so your sum is $\sum_{k \in \mathbf Z/(p)} (\frac{k+1}{p})\omega_p^{kl} - 1$. Now you're summing over an additive group, so replacing $k$ with $k-1$ makes it $\sum_{k \in \mathbf Z/(p)} (\frac{k}{p})\omega_p^{(k-1)l} - 1 = \omega_p^{-l}\sum_{k \in \mathbf Z/(p)} (\frac{k}{p})\omega_p^{kl} - 1$, and omitting the $k=0$ term (which is $0$) and then doing a multiplicative change of variable you get $\omega_p^{-l}(\frac{l}{p})\sum_{k \not\equiv 0 \bmod p} (\frac{k}{p})\omega_p^k - 1$. This last sum is a standard Gauss sum of the Legendre symbol.

Comment: @KConrad: I suggest you give your comment as a response below, and then this question can be closed.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! this was super-easy :) also, instead of $(\frac{l}{p})$ I believe what comes out is $(\frac{l^{-1}}{p})$

Comment: Could we keep the question open for the case $(\frac{k^2+k}{p})$? I could edit the question.. Similar trick I think can not be done in that case..

Comment: @Liss, first of all you are right that $(\frac{l}{p})^{-1}$ comes out, but the character is *quadratic* so the exponent doesn't matter: $a^{-1} = a$ if $a = \pm 1$. Concerning a sum with $(\frac{k^2+k}{p}) = (\frac{k(k+1)}{p})$ in it,  replacing $k$ with $-k$ makes that $(\frac{-1}{p})(\frac{k(1-k)}{p})$ and then you basically have a Jacobi sum, which you can look up elsewhere.  This is not really a research-level question. I suggest if you have similar questions that you ask them on math.stackexchange.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I understand. I it true I didn't estimate the hardness of the question correctly, I will start with math.stackexchange next time. Thanks a lot for your help and explanations!

Comment: Are you trying to count how often consecutive numbers $k$ and $k+1$ in $\mathbf Z/(p)$ are perfect squares?

Comment: This is a finite field hypergeometric sum. There is no simple formula, but it's bounded by $2\sqrt{p}$.

Comment: Whoops, my previous comment on Jacobi sums was incorrect since the sum is not just $\sum_{k \in \mathbf Z/(p)} (\frac{k(k+1)}{p})$ but has the factor $\omega_p^{kl}$ in there too.  Replacing $k$ with $k/l$ makes the sum $\sum_{k \in \mathbf Z/(p)} (\frac{k(k+l)}{p})\omega_p^k$. I agree with Will that it is hopeless to expect an exact formula for this but it gets a bound like $2\sqrt{p}$ from the Weil conjectures.

Comment: @WillSawin, thank you. Is that an upper or lower bound? Could you give me some reference?

KConrad, what I try to do is to find a lower bound for a sum of roots of unity taken over a set $k \in K, k-q \in K,$ for fixed $q,$ where $K$ is a quadratic difference set, i.e. elements of the form $t^2, t \in Z_p^*.$ I need it for  an estimate of the coherence of a Gabor system generated by difference sets...

Comment: @Liss It's an upper bound on the absolute value. For a reference you can go back to Weil: "On Some Exponential Sums". Example 1 after equation (5) on the bottom of page 206 is the bound, where $\mathfrak d=\{0,-1\}$ so $R_{\mathfrak d}(t) = t(t+1)$, $\chi$ is the quadratic character, and $\psi(x) = \omega_p^{lx}$.

Comment: thank you a lot, @KConrad and Will Sawin. It looked like these bounds can be sufficient for what I need, but when all expression taken together (with $\chi(X)$ as in the question posed), I get only $\geq -2\sqrt{p}-2$ which is useless, because I need to  show that their absolute values are away from zero.

Comment: Some Kloosterman sums involving a quadratic character *are* zero. I'm not saying yours might be zero, but if you are looking for some off-the-shelf result that will prove character sums $S$ in some family do not equal $0$ then you will be disappointed.  The standard task for exponential sums is to get sharp *upper bounds*, not lower bounds away from $0$. Saying there is a lower bound that is a negative number is not really the point of these bounds which is to say $|S|$ is less than or equal to some sharp value.

Comment: Your sum in absolute value is at least $(4p)^{(2-p)/2}$. See my response below.

Comment: thank you, @KConrad, my interest is coming from signal processing (discrete time-frequency analysis), and it is just very beautiful "coincidence" that I am dealing with quadratic characters and uncommon questions for those sums.. I can prove that this particular type of sums is non-zero, but it would have been nice to show that it is away from zero in absolute value..

Comment: thank you, @GHfromMO, too :) I will comment also below on your response

Comment: @WillSawin, maybe this is a trivial question, but the same bound $2\sqrt{p}$ also holds if it was $R(t)=t(t+\ell),$ too? I made a mistake in my question, so I need to have $k(k+l)$, or and $k(k+1)$ is just the case of $l=1,$ in which in the exponent there should be also no $l...$ But I guess the bounds  , both lower and upper do not change from this fact?

Comment: @Liss Yes, the same bound from the same proof in both cases. In fact it's the same sum- to see this, multiply the variable by $l$, and you get an $l^2$ in the exponent.

Answer (score 6):

We may assume that $l\not\equiv 0\pmod p$ because otherwise the given sum is simple. The answer is a [Kloosterman sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kloosterman_sum).

Let $$\delta_q(x)=\begin{cases}
1,& \text{if } x\equiv 0\pmod{q};\\
0,& \text{if } x\not\equiv 0\pmod{q}.\\
\end{cases}$$
Then
\begin{gather*}
S(l)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}\left(\dfrac{k(k+1)}{p}\right)e\left(\dfrac{kl}{p}\right)=\\=
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}\left(\sum\limits_{y=1}^{p}\delta_p(k(k+1)-y^2)-1\right)e\left(\dfrac{kl}{p}\right)=\\=
\sum\limits_{k,y=1}^{p}\delta_p(k(k+1)-y^2)e\left(\dfrac{kl}{p}\right)=[k=x+y]=\\=
\sum\limits_{x,y=1}^{p}\delta_p(x^2+2xy+x+y)e\left(\dfrac{(x+y)l}{p}\right).
\end{gather*}
For each non-zero summand $y=\dfrac{x^2+x}{2x+1}$. Hence
\begin{gather*}
S(l)=
\sum\limits_{\substack{1\leq x\leq p\\x\neq (p-1)/2}}e\left(\dfrac{l}{p}\cdot\left(\dfrac{x^2+x}{2x+1}+x\right)\right)=[t=2x+1]=\\=
\sum\limits_{t=1}^{p-1}e\left(\dfrac{l}{p}\cdot\left(\dfrac{3t}{4}-\dfrac{1}{4t}-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right),
\end{gather*}
where the expression $\dfrac{3t}{4}-\dfrac{1}{4t}-\dfrac{1}{2}$ is understood modulo $p$.

Comment: Thank you for a different insight! I didn't follow all the details, but in any case, this calculations gives us only a reformulation of the problem, and not a solution that I can use for my research.. - Do you have an idea, if such sums can be bounded from below by something away from 0?

Comment: I think it is impossible. For $p$ an odd prime, there are no known simple formula for $K(a, b; p)$, and the Sato–Tate conjecture suggests that none exist, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5455v2 .

Comment: @Liss What kind of lower bound do you need? (For all $p$, or for infinitely many $p$?)

Comment: It would be nice to have any bound I can get, only that it doesn't go to zero as $p$ goes to infinity. The main point is to show that it is "safe" to divide by this value in a algorithm for signal processing which I have.. 
That's why an answer like $4p^{(2-p)/2}$ will not solve my problem. 
I can test numerically how those sums behave for small $p$,   and they vary, but they are larger than at least $0.02$ or so..

Comment: @Liss, if all you test is a *finite* set of primes $p$, especially what you call "small" $p$, then of course you'll find a positive lower bound on them. But is there any reason to expect over *all* $p$ that the sums don't include values that get arbitrarily small? When you're dealing with a family of exponential sums (in your case, varying over *all* primes), even if individually they are never $0$ it doesn't mean particular values couldn't get arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: @KConrad, it is true, there is no reason to believe that over all $p$ the sums will bounded away from zero.. I was basically trying my luck :). But actually, after I found the bound $n^{-(p-3)/4}$ which is true for any subset of dimension $n,$ I thought that maybe the fact that I have a structured set (coming from quadratic difference sets) could give me a better estimate, so I posed this question.. But apparently this structure is also already investigated via the Kloosterman sums, and there is not much hope for better bound.

Comment: @Liss Will it be enogth if almost all sums (in terms of $l$) will be bounded from below?

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov, yes, if I have result that for almost all $l$ the sums are bounded, it would be also nice :)

Answer (score 3):

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\omega_p]$, the OP's second sum $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k^2+k}{p}\right) \omega_p^{kl}$ raised to the $p$-th power is congruent to 
$\sum_{k=1}^{p-2} \left(\frac{k^2+k}{p}\right)$ modulo $p$. This new sum consists of $p-2$ terms, each equal to $\pm 1$, hence it is invertible modulo $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ (hence also in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega_p]$) when $p>2$. We conclude that the OP's second sum is a nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}[\omega_p]$, which can be turned into an exponential lower bound, and perhaps even a better one (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46068/how-small-can-a-sum-of-a-few-roots-of-unity-be) for a related discussion).

**P.S.** This argument was inspired by Alexey Ustinov's response to the OP's question and Noam Elkies's response [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/166297/is-weils-bound-for-kloosterman-sums-ever-attained/), more precisely by Lucia's comment to Noam Elkies's response.

**Added 1.** As Alexey Ustinov remarked below, $\sum_{k=1}^{p-2} \left(\frac{k^2+k}{p}\right)=-1$. In fact this follows from his response to the OP's question by setting $l=0$ there and making the obvious modifications.

**Added 2.** Here is a slight variation of the above argument. The sums $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k^2+k}{p}\right) \omega_p^{kl}$ for $1\leq l\leq p-1$ are Galois conjugates in the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$, while their sum equals
$$ \sum_{l=1}^{p-1}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k^2+k}{p}\right) \omega_p^{kl}=-\sum_{k=1}^{p-2} \left(\frac{k^2+k}{p}\right)=1.$$
Hence all the sums $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k^2+k}{p}\right) \omega_p^{kl}$ for $1\leq l\leq p-1$ are nonzero. Moreover, their product is a nonzero rational integer, which also implies (by bounding the relevant Kloosterman sums from above) that each of them has length
$$ \left| \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k^2+k}{p}\right) \omega_p^{kl}\right|>(4p)^{(2-p)/2}.$$

Comment: Isn't Elkies's answer about ruling out the maximal size $2\sqrt{p}$ for Kloosterman sums, rather than zero?

Comment: @Lucia: I think Elkies proves that the Kloosterman sum is not in the prime ideal $(1-\omega_p)$, which rules out zero. Anyways, I gave a direct argument based on your version of Elkies's proof, please check! (I am too sleepy now.)

Comment: Yes indeed!  I forgot about my comment!

Comment: $$\sum_{x=1}^p \biggl(\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{p}\biggr)=p\delta_p(a-b)-1.$$

Comment: thank you, @GHfromMO, this is also interesting approach to know. I already have found similar bound in the work of Konyagin, S.V. and Lev, V.F. (2000) "On the distribution of exponential sums". Theorem 1 there says that a sum of roots of unity taken over a set of $n$ elements is bounded in absolute value from below by $n^{-(p-3)/4}.$ I can use this result to show that the full sum from the beginning of the question (with the prescribed $\chi(k)$) is bounded by $(\frac{p-3}{4})^{-(p-3)/4}.$ Still, as I wrote in some other comment, I was curious to know if a bound away from zero can be obtained.

Comment: @Liss: I am pretty sure your sums are not bounded away from zero, i.e. they can be arbitrary small for large $p$. (I don't have a proof though.)

Comment: Ok, thank you! I really appreciate your intuition and all the hints. This is not my field, so I was not sure if this was a feasible question. It was worth trying though :), and learning a small bit of the beautiful mathematics behind those questions..